# How do I set a different header and footer when on different page on my website

Tags: wordpress, header, footer, multilingual

I'm making a multilingual website. I'm doing it with one domain so abc.de will forward to abc.com/de (german) and abc.com will our into abc.com/en (english) as default. Now I have a problem with my footer and header. Since it's the same website the content on these both will be also the same, no matter on which page.

Does one have an idea how I can solve it, so it's working for google's seo and my visitors?

I'm using the salient theme and don't want to use any language plug-in, because they don't translate everything very well, as from my experience. Or can you recommend me a good one where I still can translate the content myself? If so whats the advantage of this plugin in comparison with my solution?

Have a great day you all!

Comment: Do not getting your question...

Comment: Within a child theme, create a new page template and two new header/footer template parts. Within this new template you can call in those different header/footer template parts.

Comment: @David.J Sounds good, so you mean I can then select which one has to appear under the page attributes and then template?

Comment: @PriyankaModi I need different header and footer for the English and German page wihthin one domain or website

Comment: Yes, when you create/edit a page you would choose your alt header/footer template.

Comment: All right thank you!

Comment: @David.J I'm quiet new to Coding. Do you think this will work if done correctly? https://www.webascender.com/blog/create-multiple-headers-footers-wordpress/ Seems so easy. I'm anxious to crash the site (again).

Comment: It's a different approach, right? I don't even understand where I can then edit the footer since I have two which one will I be editing when making changes to the widget section?

Comment: Yes, in theory that is correct. They instruct you to create two new template parts also, header-new.php and footer-new.php. Do all your dev work anywhere but the live server and be sure you have wp_debug set to true.

Comment: Good idea men, thats exactly what I'll do!